# Javascript memory leak issue - promises & recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion, memory-leaks, deferred

I'm having memory issues with this piece of code:

```
var RequestManager = function(customRequestArgs){

    var requestManager = this;

    this.customRequestArgs = customRequestArgs              || [];



    this.CustomRequest = function(url, data){

        var requestDeferred = $.Deferred();

        // set default xmlRequestArgs
        var xmlRequestArgs = {
            method  : "GET",
            url     : url,
            onload  : function(response) {
                requestDeferred.resolve(response.responseText);
            },
            onerror : function(response){
                requestDeferred.reject('xmlRequest failed', response);
            }
        };
        // set custom xmlRequestArgs
        var i;
        for(i in requestManager.customRequestArgs){
            if(requestManager.customRequestArgs.hasOwnProperty(i)){
                xmlRequestArgs[i] = requestManager.customRequestArgs[i];
            }
        }

        // append data, depending on method
        var d = [];
        for(i in data){
            if(data.hasOwnProperty(i)){
                d.push(i+'='+encodeURIComponent(data[i]));
            }
        }
        var dataString = d.join('&');

        if(xmlRequestArgs.method.toLowerCase() === 'get'){
            if(url.indexOf('?')>=0){
                xmlRequestArgs.url = url+dataString;
            }
            else{
                xmlRequestArgs.url = url+'?'+dataString;
            }
        }
        if(xmlRequestArgs.method.toLowerCase() === 'post'){
            xmlRequestArgs.data = dataString;
        }


        // run request
        GM_xmlhttpRequest(xmlRequestArgs);

        return requestDeferred;
    };

    this.BatchRequestRunner = function(args){

        var maxParallelRequests = args.maxParallelRequests || 8;

        var onEachStart         = args.onEachStart              || function(requestIndex, url){return undefined;};          // must return undefined or loader promise (i.e. for cached results)
        var onEachSuccess       = args.onEachSuccess            || function(result, requestIndex, url){return result;};     // must return result or promise that resolves to result
        var onEachError         = args.onEachError              || function(error, requestIndex, url){return error;};       // must return error or promise that resolves to error

        var urlAr               = args.urlAr                    || [];

        var storeResults        = args.storeResults             || false;

        var reversedUrlArClone  = urlAr.slice(0).reverse();
        var deferredAr          = [];
        var resultAr            = [];
        var errorAr             = [];


        var runnerMethod = function(){

            if(reversedUrlArClone.length > 0){

                // get request url
                var url = reversedUrlArClone.pop();

                // get urlIndex (i-th url in urlAr)
                var requestIndex = urlAr.length - reversedUrlArClone.length - 1;


                // run onEachStart
                $.when(onEachStart(requestIndex, url)).then(function(loaderPromise){

                    if(loaderPromise === undefined){

                        // set loaderPromise
                        loaderPromise = requestManager.CustomRequest(url);

                    }

                    var generateOnSuccess = function(requestIndex){
                        return function(result){


                            $.when(onEachSuccess(result, requestIndex, url)).then(function(result){

                                // store result
                                if(storeResults){
                                    resultAr[requestIndex] = result;
                                }

                                // resolve deferredAr[requestIndex]
                                deferredAr[requestIndex].resolve();

                                // start runnerMethod for next request
                                runnerMethod();

                            });

                        };
                    };
                    var generateOnError = function(requestIndex){
                        return function(error){

                            $.when(onEachError(error, requestIndex, url)).then(function(error){

                                // store error
                                errorAr[requestIndex] = error;

                                // reject deferredAr[requestIndex]
                                deferredAr[requestIndex].reject();

                                // start runnerMethod for next request
                                runnerMethod(); 


                            });

                        };
                    };

                    // handle loader
                    loaderPromise.done(generateOnSuccess(requestIndex));
                    loaderPromise.fail(generateOnError(requestIndex));

                });

            }

        };

        var startParallelRequestThread = function(){
            runnerMethod();
        };

        var start = function(){
            var i,
                runnerDeferred  = $.Deferred();

            // setup deferredAr
            for(i=0;i<urlAr.length;i++){
                deferredAr.push($.Deferred());
            }

            // setup onSuccess
            $.when.apply($, deferredAr)
            .done(function(){
                runnerDeferred.resolve(resultAr);
            })
            // setup onError
            .fail(function(){
                runnerDeferred.reject(errorAr);
            });

            // start requestThreads
            for(i=0;i<maxParallelRequests;i++){
                startParallelRequestThread();
            }

            return runnerDeferred;
        };


        return {
            start       : start
        };

    };



    return {
        BatchRequestRunner  : this.BatchRequestRunner,
        CustomRequest       : this.CustomRequest,
    };
};
```

It should be a class to perform batch requests. The user has the ability to set default request parameters (additional headers etc) and a bunch of batch-settings.

While the code performs as expected, the browser crashes after a while. Checking the task manager shows me the tab's process eats up more and more memory. 
I've been trying to find the reason for this, but have been unable to. Anyone has any ideas please?

Please let me know if I can clearify anything.

Regards,
klmdb

Comment: Could you determine what exactly is leaking via Chrome developer tools(Profiler)? I guess you have to nullify `requestDeferred` after a response(success/error).

Comment: I've tried using the Chrome profiler once, but didn't seem to be able to wrap my head around it.

I've also thought that the `requestDeferred` object might be to blame, but I haven't been able to unset it inbetween iterations. I've tried `delete loaderPromise;` but that didn't seem to have much of an effect.

Also, I tried `setTimeout(runnerMethod);` instead of just calling `runnerMethod();`, in the hope that this would clear the stack, along with any lingering references, inbetween iterations, but also without any apparent effect.

Comment: You have to use the profiler, otherwise I will be impossible. It isn't that hard. **Step 1**: open the suspected leaking screen and close it. **Step 2**: press F12 and go to the Profiles tab. Select 'take heap snapshot'. **Step 3**: Check if the object is still available(E.g.: RequestManager) and click on this object. **Step 4**: See where the object distance is equal to 0.

Comment: In trying to study your code, this line doesn't seem right: `var requestIndex = urlAr.length - reversedUrlArClone.length - 1;`.  It seems like it should be: `var requestIndex = reversedUrlArClone.length;`.  Because you are getting each url with `.pop()`, you are processing the array from back to front so the index of the element you are popping is just the length of that array after you called `.pop()`.  Or, you could go front to back by using `.shift()` instead of `.pop()`.  I don't know if this causes memory issues specifically, but doesn't look quite right.

Comment: How do you know you have memory issues?  What exact symptoms do you see?  Are you sure you aren't just in a continuing process that doesn't finish?

Comment: It's hard to imagine circumstances under which you might need an array of Deferred objects.

Comment: @jfriend00: `requestIndex` is set to the index of the url in the supplied url array `urlAr, not the index in the `reversedUrlArClone`.@jfriend00: I know there are memory issues because when I leave the code running, the process of the tab continues to consume more and more memory until it crashes. I perform perhabs 20,000 request in one batch, sending the results for each to a different server for storage (done in `onEachSuccess`), so they shouldn't stay in memory. Perhaps there's an issue in `onEachSuccess`, but I don't see how that could be so I wanted to verify the batchRunner first.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 I use an array of deferreds to be able to easily detect a bunch of async operations finishing. Should this not be done in this way?

Comment: @GuyT I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean by "see where the object distance is 0". Could you maybe elaborate please?

Comment: It's hard to advise, I'd need a day to work through everything. However, it seems safe to say that there must be a better way.

Comment: OK, didn't see the `.reverse()` earlier.  That's a complication you sure don't need.  Definitely complicates understanding the code, though it is not the problem you're asking about.

Comment: When you have selected the object, there will be more information available on the bottom of the screen. You can determine where the object is held if you look at the column **distance**. FYI: you have a memory when there is still a reference to an object. In your situaton that is definitely the case. You are pushing each time new objects to the `deferredAr` array.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I think I've got my mind round the code and it appears that you jump though a number of unneccessary hoops. The code can be greatly simplified chiefly through the use of two standard tricks :

- Use of `$.extend()` (in two places) which avoids the need to manually loop through objects.
- Use of `Array.prototype.reduce()` to transform an array into a .then() chain in lieu of "recursion".

Other features of the version below are :

- Results and errors are delivered via the promise chain, not accumulated in outer arrays.
- The need for `requestIndex` (in many places) disappears, as does the need for explicit closures for its maintenance.
- No Deferred objects are created, which should help make the executable less memory hungry.
- `new` is now optional when calling `RequestManager()`. The original code was ambiguous with regard to whether or not `new` was intended.

Here's the simplified version ...

```
var RequestManager = function(customRequestArgs) {
    var CustomRequest = function(url, data) {
        //GM_xmlhttpRequest is assumed to call $.ajax() (or one of its shorthand methods) and return a jqXHR object
        return GM_xmlhttpRequest($.extend({ //$.extend() replaces several lines of original code
            method: "GET",
            url: url,
            data: data
        }, customRequestArgs || {})).then(function(response) {
            return response.responseText;
        }, function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            return ('xmlRequest failed: ' + textStatus);
        });
    };
    //Defaults are best defined (once per RequestManager) as an object, which can be extended with $.extend().
    var batchRequestDefaults = {
        maxParallelRequests: 8,
        onEachStart: function(url) { return undefined; }, // must return undefined or loader promise (i.e. for cached results)
        onEachSuccess: function(result, url){ return result; }, // must return result or promise that resolves to result
        onEachError: function(error, url){ return error; }, // must return error or promise that resolves to error.
        urlAr: [],
        storeResults: false
    };
    var BatchRequestRunner = function(args) {
        args = $.extend({}, batchRequestDefaults, args); //$.extend() replaces several lines of original code
        function runnerMethod(index, urlAr) {
            //Note recursion is avoided here by the use of .reduce() to build a flat .then() chain.
            return urlAr.reverse().reduce(function(promise, url) {
                var requestIndex = index++;
                return promise.then(function(result1) {
                    return $.when(args.onEachStart(requestIndex, url)).then(function(p) {
                        return (p === undefined) ? CustomRequest(url) : p;
                    }).then(function(result2) {
                        args.onEachSuccess(result2, requestIndex, url);
                        // No return value is necessary as result2 is assumed 
                        // to be fully handled by onEachSuccess(),
                        // so doesn't need to be passed down the promise chain.
                    }, function(error) {
                        // This is messy but : 
                        // (a) is consistent with the stated rules for writing onEachError() functions.
                        // (b) maintains the original code's behaviour of keeping going despite an error.
                        // This is achieved by returning a resolved promise from this error handler.
                        return $.when(args.onEachError(error, requestIndex, url)).then(function(error) {
                            return $.when(); //resolved promise
                        });
                    });
               });
            }, $.when());
        }
        var start = function() {
            // start requestThreads
            var i, promises = [],
                pitch = Math.ceil(args.urlAr / args.maxParallelRequests),
                startIndex, endIndex;
            for(i=0; i<args.maxParallelRequests; i++) {
                startIndex = pitch * i;
                endIndex = pitch * (i + 1) - 1;
                promises.push(runnerMethod(startIndex, args.urlAr.slice(startIndex, endIndex)));
            }
            // Note: Results and errors are assumed to be fully handled by onEachSuccess() and onEachError() so do not need to be handled here or passed on down the promise chain.
            return $.when.apply(null, promises);
        };
        return {
            start: start
        };
    };
    return {
        BatchRequestRunner: BatchRequestRunner,
        CustomRequest: CustomRequest
    };
};
```

*untested so may well need debugging*

The hardest aspect by far is the treatment of errors. The original code has rather odd behaviour in this regard, which I have tried to emulate through the use of faux (non-stopping) errors. Messy-messy but having purged the recursion, I can't think of another way to do it.

Barring errors on my part, the only difference in behaviour should be in the promise returned by `start()`, which will now deliver both a results array AND a (faux) errors array, bundled into a js plain object. This is consistent with `runnerMethod` keeping going despite errors.

Now that results are delivered via the promise chain, 'storeResults' has disappeared. I can't see any reason for ever wanting to run with anything other than `storeResults === true`.

My only(?) assumptions are that `$` is jQuery and that `GM_xmlhttpRequest` employs `jQuery.ajax()` and returns (or can be made to return) its `jqXHR` object. This seems reasonable from what I can see. If the assumption is not valid, then you will need to revert that section of the code.

For further explanation see in-code comments.

When debugged, if it still crashes out, then I would suggest that it is just memory hungry rather than leaky *per se*.

**EDIT**

Having read (in comments below) descriptions of the batch process and `onEachError()` etc, `start()` and `runnerMethod()` have been edited above.

Summary of changes :

- Batch definition: start() now initiates its 8 parallel batches by passing *slices* of `urlAr` to runnerMethod().
- `requestIndex`: is reinstated in a very simple way.

The behaviour of the edited version is similar but not identical to that of the original code in the question. The difference is that each batch is *predefined*, not responsive.

Ultimately, removing the responsive behaviour may be a price worth paying if this version is less memory hungry and actually runs to completion, which is the object of the exercise.

*To see the unedited code, see the question's edit history*

Comment: Thanks for the help! Some remarks though:  
  
 ---- GM_xmlhttpRequest is an ajax-like method supplied by GreaseMonkey and TamperMonkey that allows ajax requests to external hosts. It has a different API than JQuery's $.ajax() so it must still get a Deferred wrapper.

Comment: ---- $.extend() seems very usefull. Thanks for pointing it out!
---- Array.prototype.reduce() is interesting; I didn't know it. It seems like it'd be a good iterator in many cases. However, here I'm not sure you used it correctly; the idea of the BatchRequestRunner is to run a bunch of requests in `maxParallelRequests` parallel treads. In your code, it looks like the same array of urls is called `maxParallelRequests` times.

Comment: ---- `requestIndex` is required as an argument to `onEachStart`, `onEachSuccess` & `onEachError`

Comment: ---- `storeResults` was provided with the idea of having the batchrunner store each seperate request's results and return them all together when the batch job is done. On second consideration, however, I don't think it's necessary for the batchRunner to store these results, ever, since onEachSuccess can handle & store them.

Comment: I'll take to time to study your code more closely later, I haven't the time now. It looks like there's quite some things in there I can learn from though!

Comment: @klmdb, I think you've picked up on all the points I wondered about when working of the code. You're right about GM_xmlhttpRequest, I should have looked it up. I'll check the batch/reduce behaviour against your original code - it's quite possible I made a mistake in that area.

Comment: @klmdb, could you do two things for me please (i) explain in words the batch process (ii) give an example of how `requestIndex` might be used in `onEachStart`/`onEachSuccess`/`onEachError`.

Comment: ---- intended behaviour of `BatchRequestRunner`: given an array of urls, perform a request to each url. Run a method `onEachStart(requestIndex, url)`before starting each request, and run methods `onEachSuccess(result, requestIndex, url)` and `onEachError(error, requestIndex, url)` when the request finishes. The `BatchRequestRunner` should aim to run as many requests as possible in as little time as possible; to this end it should perform several requests in parallel (as set by `maxParallelRequests`).

Comment: ---- example of `onEachStart(requestIndex, url)`: mainly for logging and progressbar

Comment: ---- example of `onEachSuccess(result, requestIndex, url)`: merge data from `result` into the corresponding object `objectCollection[requestIndex]`, which is being managed outside of the scope of `BatchRequestRunner`.

Comment: ---- example of `onEachError(error, requestIndex, url)`: used for logging, exception throwing and/or any other error handling in the broader scope. `requestIndex` is again used to know which is the corresponding object in the collection from which the `urlArray` was built.

Comment: ---- in other words; I have a collection of objects, from each of which I build a url. I perform each url and want to add the result into the corresponding object. To know which of the collection's element was the object that the url was built from, I pass `requestIndex` as an argument to `onEachStart`, `onEachSuccess` and `onEachError`. I need the `requestIndex` because the order of request execution cannot be guaranteed since we're performing several of them in parallel.

Comment: ---- also note that the `BatchRequestRunner` should not just run 8 requests at once, wait for all of them to finish and then run the next 8. Instead, there should constantly be 8 requests running untill all requests have been handled.

Comment: @klmdb, thanks that helps a lot. This is getting a bit heavy for comments, so I'll post an edit to my answer ... but not right now as I have a bunch of other stuff that is becoming urgent. Maybe later this evening or tomorrow.

Comment: @klmdb, see Edit above.